# Why do we set the jsonRequest parameter to null in jsonArrayRequest?

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-studio

I am writing a simple JSONArrayRequest. This is my JSONArrayRequest:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
```

I'm confused on why we set the jsonRequest parameter in JsonArrayRequest to null. The only docs I found was this: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request, which didn't really explain much. If somebody could explain this, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonRequest` as the name suggests json in request means something as payload you want to pass onto the server.

**GET**: is the type of HTTP method used for getting some info from the server and in that case we usually don't have to pass any payload to the server hence the `jsonRequest` is null in that case means the body will be empty in your API request.

**POST/PUT**: is the type of HTTP method used for creating/updating info on the server and in that case we have to pass any payload to server hence the `jsonRequest` is non-null in that case means the body will be the json data which we will pass as `jsonRequest` in your API request.

**Update:**

`jsonRequest` is of type `JSONArray` in `JsonArrayRequest`, so you can just convert your arraylist into jsonarray and pass it on.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("hello");
list.add("CodingChap");
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(list);
```

Comment: Also, one more thing. What would be the use cases of sending data as a jsonRequest in JsonArrayRequest?(i.e. what would the JsonArrayRequest do with this data). Thanks.

Comment: data which you sent with your API request is also called payload

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/com.android.volley/volley/1.1.1/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonArrayRequest.html) says, the parameters of `JsonArrayRequest` are:

> method - the HTTP method to use

> url - URL to fetch the JSON from

> jsonRequest - A JSONArray to post with the request. Null indicates no parameters will be posted along with request

> listener - Listener to receive the JSON response

> errorListener - Error listener, or null to ignore errors

So the null value you're passing is for the parameters to post along with the request, which can be null if you have nothing to pass.

Comment: You're essentially passing information to the server to go along with your request, which is not generally needed if you're just making a simple request.